# Increase reputation requirements for creating a new tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation, portuguese-stackoverflow

In http://pt.stackoverflow.com these occur several problems with users creating unnecessary tags.

This has affected who is collaborating with the community [portuguese-stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/portuguese-stackoverflow), because instead of answering questions spend a lot of time editing and removing tags deemed unnecessary.

In the http://www.stackoverflow.com is needed 1500 points.

We are no longer [*BETA to approximately 1 year*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539?phase=beta), there are already many users with high scores and when the score required to create a tag is only 300 points (today it is easy to achieve), it is very low.

Is there the possibility to increase to 1500 points?

> Related: [Aumentar reputação necessária pra se criar tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/3635)

Comment: You should ask this on the [Portuguese Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/). I'm not going to migrate it because it's in English here.

Comment: @animuson can we decide inside the community a different threshold for reputation/tag-creation? Is it not the same number for all sites in SE?

Comment: @animuson if I edit the request to all sites that are no longer "BETA",
could I reopen the question? [Sorry my bad english]

Comment: @Sergio It's a per-site setting. -- I've pinged someone to look into the request on Portuguese Meta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Yes, but that request would likely be declined. Many graduated sites on our network do not have any need for a heightened requirement to create tags, and it would probably be detrimental to some.

Comment: @animuson and if I edit and add only stackoverflows (Spanish, Russian, Portuguese and Turkish)?

Comment: We don't have a Turkish Stack Overflow, but this is still something that should be brought up on each site individually. For example, I don't believe the Japanese Stack Overflow would appreciate this change.

Comment: @animuson Ok, I give up sending any suggestion ([including on-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A198279+%5Bfeature-request%5D)), but thank you anyway, Bye! :)